# Debian 11. Как запретить доступ ко всем портам, кроме 80 и 443?

Tags: iptables, firewall

Имеется сервер Debian 11, необходимо оставить общедоступными порты 80, 8080 и 443, остальные порты должны быть доступны только для определенного списка IP адресов.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте список IP адресов (назовем его whitelist) утилитой [ipset](https://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html):

```
ipset create whitelist hash:net family inet
```

Используйте утилиту ipset для добавления или удаления IP.

Если стоит дефолтная политика на INPUT ACCEPT то пропишите правило iptables:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 22,80,8080,443 -m set ! --match-set whitelist src -j REJECT
```